# How to write a mixin in this case in order not to repeat the code

Tags: django

Django==2.2.5

There are three levels logically nested one inside another.
The problem here is the repeating code in save method.

Could you help me create a mixin not to repeat myself.

```
class Level_1(PhraseMixin, ArchivedMixin, models.Model):

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        """
        If this level is archived, then make all sublevels archived too.
        """
        if self.archived:
            level_2_set = self.level_2_set.all()
            for level_2_obj in level_2_set:
                level_2_obj.archived = True
                level_2_obj.save()

        super(Level_1, self).save(*args, **kwargs)



class Level_2(ArchivedMixin,
              PhraseMixin,
              ValidateParentMixin,
              models.Model):
    parent_level = models.ForeignKey(Level_1,
                                     verbose_name="Level 1",
                                     on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        If this level is archived, then make all sublevels archived too.
        """


        if self.archived:
            level_3_set = self.level_3_set.all()
            for level_3_obj in level_3_set:
                level_3_obj.archived = True
                level_3_obj.save()

        super(Level_2, self).save(*args, **kwargs)    


class Level_3(PhraseMixin,
              ArchivedMixin,
              WhereMixin,
              ValidateParentMixin,
              models.Model):
    parent_level = models.ForeignKey(Level_2,
                                     verbose_name="Level 2",
                                     on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing `def save(self, *args, **kwargs):` declaration in class `Level_2`

Comment: @Daniel Holmes, thank you for you comment. I missed just one line when copied my code here. It is edited now.

Comment: Why not make one class, and write some sort of validation to make sure that the maximum depth of nested levels is 3?

Comment: @Michael Nico's question is worth considering - you didn't provide any context and there might (or not...) be better designs to start with - IOW this might (or not...) be a XY problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Also, looping over models instances and saving them one by one is highly inefficient (and unsafe wrt/ race conditions) compared to a direct `queryset.update()` operation

Comment: @Michael If you could provide some more context as to what you are trying to achieve, we may be able to help you better.